# Can't get System.exit() to work in dragon12 project

Tags: java

I have everything working but the `System.exit(0)`.  It should exit any time remaining if the button is pressed.  I'm not sure what to do.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    /*
     Creates the perfect hard-boiled(simulates 12 minutes in boiling water) or soft-boiled
     egg(simulates 6 minutes in boiling water).  Both options require 10 seconds of rinsing
     under cold water after necessary time for boiling.  Allow user to exit any remaining 
     time.
    */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AdvancedEggMaker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MCU mcu = null;

        try {
            mcu = new MCU(new Communicator(args[0]));
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        mcu.println("SW2 - HB Egg", 0);
        mcu.println("SW3 - SB Egg", 1);

        while (true) {
            int sw = mcu.getSwitch();
            if (sw == 2) {
                mcu.println("Hard Boiled Egg", 0);
                mcu.println("Place Egg in", 0);
                mcu.println("boiling water", 1);
                mcu.println("then press SW4", 0);
                mcu.println("SW5 - Quit", 1);
                int sw2 = mcu.getSwitch();
                switch (sw2) {
                case 4:
                    int t = 720;
                    while (t > 0 && sw2 == 4) {
                        t = (t - 1);
                        mcu.println("Boiling...", 0);
                        mcu.println((t / 60) + "mins left...", 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (sw == 3) {
                mcu.println("Soft Boiled Egg", 0);
                mcu.println("Place Egg in", 0);
                mcu.println("boiling water", 1);
                mcu.println("then press SW4", 0);
                mcu.println("SW5 - Quit", 1);
                int sw2 = mcu.getSwitch();
                switch (sw2) {
                case 4:
                    int t = 360;
                    while (t > 0 && sw2 == 4) {
                        t = (t - 1);
                        mcu.println("Boiling...", 0);
                        mcu.println((t / 60) + "mins left...", 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }

            mcu.println("Rinse Egg", 0);
            mcu.println("then press SW4", 0);
            mcu.println("SW5 - Quit", 1);
            int sw3 = mcu.getSwitch();
            if (sw3 == 4) {
                double t = 10;
                while (t > 0.0) {
                    t = (t - 1);
                    mcu.println("Rinsing...", 0);
                    mcu.println(t + "Secs left...", 1);
                }
                if (sw == 5) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code of the MCU class?

Comment: You misunderstand the usage of `switch`.

Comment: check whether you have input number 5 and it goes on to execute case 5.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that the execution is reaching one of your System.exit(0) statements. I don't see any sysout or logs to help you to be sure about that. First examine that because I don't see there any reason why it should not work.

Secondly you can check whether you have some background thread working in your code. It may be the case that you may have some connections/streams open somewhere in a thread and it is not letting the System.exit(0) to terminate the process.

Comment: open connections and streams don't prevent the JVM from exiting.

Comment: I'm using the Dragon board to test.  Once sw4 is pressed it passes case4 to int sw2 = mcu.getSwitch(); and starts counting.  But when I press sw5 it doesn't change to case5, so it isn't reaching System.exit(0).  How can if fix that?